# Python keeping precision when dividing

Tags: python, division

I need to divide 2 integers and display the result to at least 76 digits of accuracy. For example, when I divide 1 by 3, I need to display 0.33333333333... with 76 "3"s. When I divide in python and make it display 76 digits after the decimal point, it doesn't give me enough digits of precision, that is, some digits are wrong. I did:

```
print(format(1/3,".76f"))
```

This gave me the result of: 0.3333333333333333148296162562473909929394721984863281250000000000000000000000, which is obviously not equal to 1/3. I am using python 3. Is there any better way of dividing and displaying decimal digits? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `decimal.Decimal`?

Comment: Thanks! I tried, but it also doesn't give me enough digits of accuracy. BTW, this is a USACO training question, "fracdec".

Comment: It did not? From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html): "Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a **user alterable precision** (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given problem)"

Comment: decimal.Decimal(1/3) gave me 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125, which was 16 correct digits, and a bunch of incorrect digits.

Comment: Why 76? . . . .

Comment: It was part of the problem statement. I needed to check the first 76 digits.

Comment: I don't think that's true. The version of the problem statement I just found says something different. Please show a link to the version you're reading.

Comment: "If the expansion exceeds 76 characters in length, print it on multiple lines with 76 characters per line." So I may need more than 76 digits. http://train.usaco.org/usacoprob2?a=s8le3lbuWap&S=fracdec

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. It might have **thousands** of characters. That 76 only tells you where to break the output into separate lines.

Comment: Your application of `Decimal` was wrong. You did the division *before* you converted to decimal.

Comment: I see. So I needed to convert to decimal first, then divide. Thanks everyone!

Comment: This USACO problem is getting harder every time I think about it. With thousands of characters in the answer, a brute force solution(what I have right now) probably won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want 76 digits right?

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 76
Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)
```

Output

```
Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333')
```

Comment: Can `Decimal` objects be passed around through json?